# SpreadsheetFormats not working as expected

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am able to populate data from a query into a spreadsheet.  However, I am having problems getting "ranged" formatting to work properly.  The formatting for specific column (date) and row (header) work fine.  But SpreadsheetFormatColumns, ...Rows, ...CellRange is not.  I need to set the font and fontsize to the whole dataset.

Here is what I have tried.

```
<cfscript>
//Current directory path.
theFile = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) &     "GridDump.xls";
//Create a new Excel spreadsheet object and add the query data.
theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("Raw Data");
FormatDate.dataformat = "dd-mmm-yy";
//Get Row Count and Row Range
RC = toString(result.recordcount+1);
RR = "1-" & RC;
//Get Column Count 
CC = toString(ListLen(GridFieldNames));
//Get Column Letter
CL = chr(CC + 64);
//Get Column Range (Nummerical)
CRN = "1-" & CC;
//Get Column Range (Alphabetical)
CRA = "A-" & CL;
//Set Sheet Format 
WholeSheet = StructNew();
WholeSheet.font="Consolas";
WholeSheet.fontsize=12;
//Set header Row Format
HeadRow = StructNew();
HeadRow.bold="true";
//Insert the Header Row
SpreadsheetAddRow(theSheet,GridFieldNames);
//Insert the Data
SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,result);
//Format the Data
SpreadsheetFormatCellRange(theSheet,WholeSheet,1,1,RC,CC);
//SpreadsheetFormatRows(theSheet,WholeSheet,RR);
//SpreadsheetFormatColumns(theSheet,WholeSheet,CRN);
SpreadsheetFormatRow(theSheet,HeadRow,1);
//Header Row
SpreadsheetFormatColumn(theSheet,FormatDate,1);//Date Column
SpreadsheetAddFreezePane(theSheet,0,1);//Top Row Only
//SpreadSheetAddAutofilter(theSheet,"A1:J1");
</cfscript>
```

Here are the results
[image: Green highlight is correct format, orange is incorrect.]

I'm getting the same result for all three of the "ranged" formatting functions.  The format stops part way through the spreadsheet.  I expect the whole dataset to accept any of the ranged function formats.

Comment: **Edit**: What version of CF - `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`? Could be a bug. I got the same result with CF 2018,0,04,314546, but using A) SpreadsheetFormatColumns() instead of SpreadsheetFormatCellRange OR B) using XLSX format instead of XLS worked for me.

Comment: @Ageax, I'm currently on CF 10,0,18,296330, but upgrades are planned. The XLSX format actually got all 3 of the above mentioned formatting functions to work properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result with CF 2018,0,04,314546. Could just be a limitation of XLS format.
Switching to XLSX worked fine for me:

```
theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("Raw Data", true);
```

YMMV, but what also worked with CF2018 was using `SpreadsheetFormatColumns()` instead of `SpreadsheetFormatCellRange()`.